# Ruby GC module undefined method `malloc_allocated_size`

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, nomethoderror

Trying to use GC module in Ruby 1.9.3

In repl (or script) getting this error

```
include GC
=> Object
GC.enable
=> false
GC.malloc_allocations
NoMethodError: undefined method `malloc_allocations' for GC:Module
```

From the [1.9.3 GC Module docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html), malloc_allocations is a public class method so why is Ruby saying that it is an undefined method?

Comment: Maybe the documentation is anomalous. I don't see that method in 1.9.3 or 2.1.5. `GC.methods - Module.methods` returns `[:start, :enable, :disable, :stress, :stress=, :count, :stat, :latest_gc_info, :verify_internal_consistency]` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are omitting that you need to edit gc.c and set `CALC_EXACT_MALLOC_SIZE` to 1 before recompiling ruby in order for this method to be available. This flag also turns on the tracking required to support this feature.

See for example https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/gc.c#L3718

Comment: Thanks! I figured something like this was occuring.